XSL, WordML: Determine if the current cell of a table is in the first row and first column
I have a working .xsl but I wanted to add a check to see if the current cell is in the first row and first cell:
    <xsl:for-each select="w:tr">
        <xsl:for-each select="w:tc[position()!=last()]">
            
            <!-- Check if first row and if is first column -->
            <xsl:if test="w:tr[position()=first()] and w:tc[position()=first()]">
            <xsl:text>\mcx</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- Check if is first row only -->
        <xsl:if test="w:tr[position()=first()] and w:tc[position()!=first()]">
            <xsl:text>\mc</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>



I am unable to apply the .xsl with these lines added. If I take them out, it works, so I know that my check isn't correct. Can someone help me with the wordML side. As I approaching this wrong?
Thanks,
Russ

Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

It is a very long .xsl, I'll try and see if I can minimize to something testable. I was really just hoping someone could tell me if the tabel and row WordML commands I was trying to use were correct?

Oh, that part is easy: they are not. But in order to fix them we need to see the context.

I am purely guessing you want to do something like:
<xsl:for-each select="w:tr">
    <xsl:variable name="is1stRow" select="position()=1" />
    <xsl:for-each select="w:tc">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$is1stRow and position()=1">
                <!-- this is the first cell in the first row -->
                <xsl:text>\mcx</xsl:text> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$is1stRow">
                <!-- this is another cell in the first row -->
                <xsl:text>\mc</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- this is a cell in another row -->
                <!-- do something here? -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>


Side note:
There is no first() function in XSLT. XSLT in not an intuitive language. You cannot succeed by trial-and-error.
